# How to return linear interpolation from a Pandas dataframe for a n-dimensional problem?

Tags: python, pandas, linear-interpolation

I'm looking to interpolate solutions described by the function `Result = Fn(x0, x1, x2, x3, x4)`

x0 has 20 values, 
x1 has 10 values, 
x2 has 6 values, 
x3 has 10 values, 
x4 has 4 values

Some of the values are linearly spaced, and others are log spaced

Total rows = `20 x 10 x 6 x 10 x 4 = 48,000`

I have a Pandas dataframe with 5 columns corresponding to each of the `x0 - x4` variables, and a 6th column corresponding to the result, and what I'm looking for is a way to pass to a function a new set of `(x0, x1, x2, x3, x4)` that are not in the dataframe and get a linear interpolated result of the 6th column.

I've been trying a few approaches with this, the first being using `LinearNDInterpolator`, but this was way too slow, even for a 'modest' 48,000 total number of rows - I never got a single result even after waiting 5mins+

I spent some time wrestling with `RegularGridInterpolator`, but couldn't figure out how to recast the pandas columns into points and values... besides I wasn't even sure if the approach would work for me given not all the columns have linearly spaced elements in them.

Would someone please be able to point me in the direction of a solution for this?

Thanks

Comment: Just to make sure i understood. You have a bunch of x and y values. When you get a new x value you need to interpolate the new y value?

Comment: Correct. The independant variables (x0 - x4) have each been generated from consistent lists, so - for example - x4 might comprise of only [0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 5], one of each of which would exist in all 48,000 cases. The y-values (dependant variable) have been pre-calculated for each case already. The goal is to be able to interpolate a new y value for any set of x0-x4 that doesnt exist in their lists (but lies within the range of each)

Comment: So far I've taken the route of moving to a numpy array, and looking up indices for each of x0-x4 that straddles the new values, working out slopes of dy/dx for each x and simply calculating that way, but it's a bit messy and was hoping there was a more elegant way